# Expectation of a function of a random variable

Tags: expected-value

Suppose $X$ is a random variable, then is it true to say that $$ E \left[ g \left( X_i \right) \right] = E\left[ g \left( X_j \right) \right] $$ ?

If so, why is that the case? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do the subscripts $i$ and $j$ represent?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Random sample.

Comment: Suppose you know the distribution of $X_i$. How is $X_j$ distributed then?

Comment: @MichaelMayer The same way since they are iid. It's the function that confuses me.

Comment: Exactly. To get rid of the function, you could just imagine the derived random sample $Y_i := g(X_i), Y_j := g(X_j)$.

Comment: @MichaelMayer The function always preserves distribution and independence?

Comment: Yes, as long as it depends on the sample only through $X_i$ resp. through $X_j$. (This assumption is even too strong.)

Comment: Independence seems irrelevant here. If $X_i$ and $X_j$ are any random variables with the same distribution, then what needs to be shown is that $E[g(X_i)]=E[g(X_j)]$ for any measurable function $g$ (see ["Law of the unconscious statistician"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician)).

Comment: @whuber If I am understanding well then, it is the same because we are summing/integrating over all the values? PS. The best name for a theorem I have ever seen.

Comment: There is a subtlety that the Wikipedia article perhaps does not sufficiently emphasize: two random variables may differ but have the same distribution. For instance, let $X_1$ be the length of a chord of a unit circle whose endpoints are obtained from two independent directions uniformly distributed on $[0,2\pi)$. Let $X_2$ be same thing, but change its value to $-1$ on all diameters of the circle. These variables, although they differ on an infinite set, still have the same distribution.

Comment: @whuber Hmm. Consider a counter example. Let $X \sim unif(0,1) $ and let $g(x) = x^2 $ We know that $E[g(x)] = 1/3 $. But now consider two specific x values i and j , say $0.5$ and $0.75$. Then $E[g(X_i)] \neq E[g(X_j)] $ I really do not understand why it must always be that they are equal.

Comment: The notation in your previous comment makes no sense: the value of a *realization,* such as "$0.5$", cannot have an expectation! You seem to be confusing the realizations with the random values used to model them. The value $0.5$ is a realization of a Uniform$[0,1]$ variable; likewise, $0.75$ is a realization of another Uniform$[0,1]$ variable. The *variables*--which are measurable real-valued functions defined on a sample space--have expectations, while their realizations are just numbers (which we anticipate will change in repetitions of the experiment).

Comment: @whuber: We don't even need to talk about expectations but about *any* distributional property $Q$ (e.g. $Q$ is the variance): $Q(g(X_i))$ will always equal $Q(g(X_j))$ as long as the two random variables have the same distribution.

Comment: @MichaelMayer Thank you Michael, I  had got a lot more confused in the meantime.

Comment: @Michael True: but the point is that you first have to show that $E[g(X)]$ truly is a *distributional* property: to assume that it is amounts to a circular argument. (I am not asserting this is anything but obvious and easy to prove, but it does need to be shown.)  The law has its memorable name because so many people appear to be unaware of this logical gap in your assertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The random variables $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution (meaning that $P(X\in A)=P(Y\in A)$ for every Borel set $A$), and you have a  measurable function $g$. First, prove it when $g=I_A$, the indicator of some Borel set $A$. What are $\mathrm{E}[I_A(X)]$ and $\mathrm{E}[I_A(Y)]$? Give it a try.

Comment: I fear that my analysis knowledge does not cover Borel sets yet. Would you mind using beginner terminology?

Comment: Borel sets and measurable functions aside, the expected value of an Indicator Function is $P(X \in A)$, same with $Y$ which are equal. But how does this generalize to functions?

Comment: If you don't have any measure theoretic training, then probably all you can do is to use the theorem (law of the unconscious statistician) $E[g(X)]=\int g(t) f(t)\,dt= E[g(Y)]$, because $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed.

Comment: Sadly I do not for the time being. While I understand what the law of the unconsious statistician says, I do not yet see how it applies to the current situation.

Comment: Returning to the measure theoretic proof: can you prove it for nonnegative simple functions $g=\sum_{i=1}^k a_i I_{A_i}$? Just use what you proved for indicators and the linearity of the expectation. Give it a try.

Comment: About your question, if you accept the law of the unconscious statistician as a fact, then you're done, right? Any doubts about this? $X$ and $Y$ have the same density $f$.

Comment: Okay, we have then $E[g(X)]= \sum a_i P(X \in A_i) = \sum a_i P(Y \in A_i)$ , right?

Comment: Perfect. From here a rigorous proof would go like this: for any nonnegative measurable $g$ function there exists an increasing sequence of nonnegative simple functions that converge to $g$. Using this and the Monotone Convergence Theorem, you prove the desired result for any nonnegative measurable $g$.

Comment: Finally, an arbitrary measurable $g$ can be written in terms of its positive and negative parts: $g=g^+-g^-$. But you already know that the result holds for the nonnegative measurable function $g^+$ and $g^-$. Hence, using the linearity of the expectation again you're done.

Comment: This is the standard measure theoretic way to prove properties of expectation, like this one. Prove it for indicators, then prove it for nonnegative simple functions, then prove it for nonnegative measurable functions, then prove it for general measurable functions. It's a technique worth remembering.

Comment: In a sense, if you can prove it for indicators, then you've got lucky.

Comment: I have so much to learn but statistics is fascinating. And you are very good at explaining. Thanks a lot.